# subprocess stdout readline() encoding error in "find" command in linux

Tags: python, subprocess, find

I have referred the other questions regarding the same error. But I would not want to specify an encoding, and just want to skip to the next line. Is it possible to `ignore errors` in `readline()` and read next?

I am using `find` utility to get files older than 30 days. and it returns the files with full path. But when a different user used the code for another path, he got the encoding error. So if there is an error in `stdout.readline()` then I want to skip the line and move to next. Does `stdout.readline()` allow something like skip on errors?

Also in this given scenario of `find` result, Can I use `utf-8` encoding and be sure the paths will be read without errors?

```
find_cmd = ['find', '/a/b', '-mtime', f'+30', '-readable', '-type', 'f', '-print']
j = ' '.join(find_cmd)
proc = subprocess.Popen(j, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

while True:
  file = proc.stdout.readline().replace('\n', '') #Error here 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1478: invalid continuation byte
  if not file: break
  movefile(file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output from `find` is not guaranteed to be UTF-8, don't use `universal_newlines=True` (aka `text=True` from Python 3.7 on).

You can selectively decode as you read, and skip the entries which are not valid UTF-8 if that's what you want.

Also, for the love of `$dmr`, don't `join` back together your perfectly good list only so that you can [waste an unnecessary `shell=True`](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) on it.

Finally, don't redirect `stderr` to `stdout` if you don't want to have error messages from `find` presented as if they were file names. Simply don't redirect `stderr` at all to have them displayed on the console, or direct `stderr` to `subprocess.DEVNULL` if you want to discard them completely.

```
find_cmd = [
    'find', '/a/b', '-mtime', f'+30', '-readable',
    '-type', 'f', '-print']
proc = subprocess.Popen(find_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)

while True:
  filename = proc.stdout.readline().replace(b'\n', b'')
  if not filename:
    break
  try:
    file = filename.decode('utf-8')
    movefile(file)
  except UnicodeDecodeError:
    logging.info('Skipping non-UTF8 filename %r' % filename)
```

You'll notice I added `check=True` to `subprocess.Popen()`; if you want to ignore `find` failures, maybe take that out again.

Comment: If your file system is not UTF-8 clean, I suspect something is wrong, or at least sinister.

Comment: i had some error with using list (i think with escaping characters in the arguments) so i had done `join` to make it work. There should have been another right approach for the fix im sure.

Comment: Could the error have been in `readline()` or in `replace()`? . as i got the error in the same line and here also the try block is after the error line..

Comment: Using a list _removes_ the need to quote anything, because the quoting is to prevent the shell from messing with strings, and of course when you don't have `shell=True` that won't happen, and then any quotes you put there anyway will be errors. But yes, it can be challenging to figure out if you don't know how the shell's quoting mechanisms work.

Comment: The error was that Python would try to `.decode()` for you implicitly when you say `text=True`. We now do the `decode` explicitly later, and catch any errors from only that operation. Maybe see also the section about `text=True` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538

Comment: It fixed my issue !!. can I ask why the byte conversion in `replace`?. I use a `filename.startswith(strvar)`  which gives error `startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str` . I think `filename.startswith(bytes(strvariable))` should fix it

Comment: Do that after you decode. It just made sense to strip the newline immediately. So then you have `file.startswith` instead of `filename.startswith` (though I suppose you could use the same variable name for the decoded value).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225485/discussion-between-sjd-and-tripleee).

Answer (score -1):

In

`find_cmd = ['find', '/a/b', '-mtime', f'+30', '-readable', '-type', 'f', '-print']`

to - (redirect errors to `/dev/null`)

`find_cmd = ['find', '/a/b', '-mtime', f'+30', '-readable', '-type', 'f', '-print','&> /dev/null']`

errors should not come

Comment: Hi @paint_program- I think the encoding error is caused by special characters in the output (in my case the file paths) while reading the output. `/dev/null` will skip the errors it finds while trying to execute the command(`find`). right?

Comment: well that solution was for skipping system error.. You can use proc.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8') ..